# Javascript error on Jsp with struts

Tags: javascript, jsp

Can anyone tell me if there is any syntax error on the html select on change where i pass the scriptlet because i see a syntax error on the browser javascript console.
Jsp code:

```
<%String variable= Somejavaclass.property;%>


<html:select name="Form" property="field" onchange="javascript:nextPage(this,<%=variable%>);">
```

It says syntax error . 
I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need "javascript:" in the onchange.  It should be:

```
onchange="newPage(this,<%=variable%>)"
```

Also, if variable is a number, you are fine, but if its a string, you will want to add quotes like:

```
onchange="newPage(this,'<%=variable%>')"
```

Comment: Thanks the onchange worked but the variable is a string and if I add quotes to it and print it using an alert it displays "<%=variable%>" instead of the actual value and if i dont add i still have the syntax error.